ROC and continuous values
So I used GradientBoostingRegressor to predict a target from a number of variables. The target is whole numbers from 0 to 27. The GradientBoostingRegressor returns y_pred_gb = reg.predict(input_test), which are also whole numbers from 0 to 27.
Then, I manually set a cutoff of 10, and convert both y_pred_gb and y_test (ground truth) to Booleans y_pred_gb_binary and y_test_binary (above 10 as positive (1), otherwise negative (0)). Thus, I have converted it to a classification problem.
How should I generate ROC curve in this case? I used this code fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test_binary, y_pred_gb). My question: Can I use y_pred_gb as the second input to roc_curve? Documentation says this should be "Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers)". How can I get the target scores?
It does generate a ROC curve for me, but the curve is very similar between different manual cutoffs, even though the accuracy increases dramatically when the manual cutoff increases. Why?
Thank you!

This question is off topic here, since it is conceptual in nature; more suitable for [stats.SE] or datascience.stackexchange.com. That said, it looks like you're trying to smash a square peg into a round hole. My advice is to back up a couple of steps and think again about what is the larger goal you are trying to achieve here. It would probably help others help you if you say something about what is the context of the problem and what you need to do with the results. Others can try to guess what's going on but it would be more efficient if you just tell them.

This question might be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/372236/36682
